# Using multiple variables from $_GET to change layout of page and MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to build a filter system for retrieving information from a MySQL database,

I searched the internet for a couple of hours, pretty much the entire day but now I'll try my luck here.

My solution started with an $_GET function in PHP but while being close to what I want it created a new problem.
What happens now is when a new filter gets applied the other one magically switches back to the default value.
I did some testing and it seemed like it was thinking the $_GET was empty but since this is clearly not the case I wasn't able to figure it out.

```php
if (isset($_GET['select'])) {
    if ($_GET['select'] == "allitems") {
        $select = "SELECT * FROM items";
    } else if ($_GET['select'] == "available") {
        $select = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE available='1'";
    }
} else if (empty($_GET['select'])) {
    $select = "SELECT * FROM items";
}
if (isset($_GET['order'])) {
    if ($_GET['order'] == "id_asc") {
        $order = "`items`.`item_id` ASC";
    } else if ($_GET['order'] == "id_desc") {
        $order = "`items`.`item_id` DESC";
    }
} else if (empty($_GET['order'])) {
    $order = "`items`.`item_id` ASC";
}
if (isset($_GET['layout'])) {
    if ($_GET['layout'] == "row") {
        $layout = "row";
    } else if ($_GET['layout'] == "grid") {
        $layout = "grid";
    }
} else if (empty($_GET['layout'])) {
    $layout = "row";
}

$s = $_GET['select'] ?? 'allitems';
$o = $_GET['object'] ?? 'id_asc';
$l = $_GET['layout'] ?? 'row';
```

the code above is where it retrieves the information from the URL,
which looks something like this: store?select=allitems&order=id_desc
It looks kind of all over the place but having the nice coding where I started didn't really help and while trying some stuff it ended up here.

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //what to show
    if (isset($_POST['allitems'])) {
        $s = "allitems";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['available'])) {
        $s = "available";
    }
    //order to show it in
    if (isset($_POST['id_asc'])) {
        $o = "id_asc";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['id_desc'])) {
        $o = "id_desc";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['allitems']) || isset($_POST['available']) || isset($_POST['id_asc']) || isset($_POST['id_desc'])) {
        $data = ['select' => $s, 'order' => $o];
        $query_string = http_build_query($data);
        header('Location: store' . (FALSE === empty($query_string) ? '?'.$query_string:''));
        exit;
    }
```

And the code above is where I was setting the values of the variables, now I'm almost positive this is not where the problem is because of the way it does still work.
Since it is able to set one value, for example when you press id_descent it gets that value and the changes take place it is only when you want two filters, id_ascent and only where available = true. That it switches the first one back to it's default state. (which is set when the $_GET is empty)

I hope this makes sense otherwise I would be happy to rephrase my question.

and last but not least if someone knows an entire different way of doing this then that's fine and then the following might help:

```
                $getItems = ("$select ORDER BY $order");
                $result = $connection->query($getItems);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) { //do stuff
```

Thanks!

ps: there are a couple of other ways I tried doing this but there were a lot more problems and errors I ran into. most of 'em were with $_SESSIONs or JavaScript, my main problem was that the changes didn't apply before you refreshed the page twice...

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this would help but this is a stripped down version of my html form on the same page,

also the page redirects to itself.

```
                        <form action="store" method="post"> 
                            <button class="a" name="allitems">
                            </button>

                            <button class="a" name="available">
                            </button>

                            <button class="a" name="id_<?php if ($o === "id_asc") {echo'desc';} else {echo'asc';}?>">
                            </button>

                            <button class="a" name="row">
                            </button>

                            <button class="a" name="grid">
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

**EDIT 2:**

*Example 1:*
[So when I choose a filter everything worked, the default states of all the other options are set][1]

*Example 2:*
[But once I choose a second one the previously selected filter is set back to it's default state][2]

Comment: Why do you use `button` instead of  `input`?

Comment: @Alex I don't know, do you think that would make any difference in this case? I've never thought about the draw backs or benifits of either of them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit off topic, but you could simplify your code pretty much:

```
                if (isset($_GET['select']) && $_GET['select'] == "available") {
                    $select = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE available='1'";
                } else {
                    $select = "SELECT * FROM items";
                }
                if (isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] == "id_desc") {
                    $order = "`items`.`item_id` DESC";
                } else {
                    $order = "`items`.`item_id` ASC";
                }
                if (isset($_GET['layout']) && $_GET['layout'] == "grid") {
                    $layout = "grid";
                } else {
                    $layout = "row";
                }
```

and another improvement:

```
                    if (isset($s) || isset($o)) {
                        $data = ['select' => $s, 'order' => $o];
                        $query_string = http_build_query($data);
                        header('Location: store' . (FALSE === empty($query_string) ? '?'.$query_string:''));
                        exit;
                    }
```

Do you want to redirect to `management?select=allitems&order=id_desc` or to `store?select=allitems&order=id_desc` (you wrote `management` in your question, but are redirecting to `store` in your code)

Comment: By the way, management was added after the fact, a bit of a problem right there. but I meant store both times and that's also what my code in reality looks like

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the query as you are collecting from the $_GET (the URL) and the $_POST which would imply you are using a form with the POST method at the same time.
I would simply things by constructing the SQL string

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM items" WHERE 1=1;//add where 1 = 1 to have the where clause in
if (isset($_GET['select'] && $_GET['select'] == "available")
{
$sqlStr .= " AND available=1";
}
//add some other criteria here

if (isset($_GET['order'] && $_GET['order'] == "id_asc")
{
$sqlStr .= " ORDER BY items.itemId DESC";
}

//now you can use the $sqlStr var in your query
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have the `POST`/form setup so that whenever an option gets chosen the page is reloaded and the changes get applied because they're put in an array in `$_GET`, This actually works the problem accures whenever a second option gets chosen and the first one gets reset for some reason... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so now it's a couple of days later and I kinda had to let this all rest.

But I've figgured it out, I actually feel the need to explain once more what I was trying to do since this might honestly be helpfull to someone out there.

**Why I did it this way**
The point of this layout was to be able to change the layout of one page.
-What items come first?
-Is it displayed in a grid or a row?
All of these kind of things from other pages.
For some reason if I just used  `$_SESSION` the changes didn't apply until the page was refreshed twice, kinda weird but whatever, also I wanted to change the layout with a quick way of refreshing without reloading the whole page if the layout was changed on the page itself.

**Where I starded**
Anyway, this lead me to the solution to use `$_GET` since the changes were able to be applied immediately. for this I used a string that held 3 variables that got applied to the url.
This is also where my solution lies.

**The solution**
At first I used just normal variables to set them in the string but I changed 'm to `$_SESSION`, this might seem weird since I was just telling you that there was a problem with this but since the information now comes from `$_GET` it can actually be written with `$_SESSION` wich helps since when I refer back to this page now from somewhere else I can use the `$_SESSION` to save the layout through the entire session wich is nice for the user.

**The code**
This is the code I ended up with:

```
                    if (isset($_GET['select']) && $_GET['select'] == "available") {
                        $select = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE available='1'";
                    } else {
                        $select = "SELECT * FROM items";
                    }

                    if (isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] == "name_asc") {
                        $order = "`items`.`name` ASC";
                    } else if (isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] == "name_desc") {
                        $order = "`items`.`name` DESC";
                    } else if (isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] == "id_desc") {
                        $order = "`items`.`item_id` DESC";
                    } else {
                        $order = "`items`.`item_id` ASC";
                    }

                    if (isset($_GET['layout']) && $_GET['layout'] == "grid") {
                        $layout = "grid";
                    } else {
                        $layout = "row";
                    }

                    $s = $_GET['select'] ?? 'allitems';
                    $o = $_GET['order'] ?? 'id_asc';
                    $l = $_GET['layout'] ?? 'row';

                    if (isset($_POST['select']) || isset($_POST['order']) || isset($_POST['layout'])) {
                        //what to show
                        if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
                            if ($_POST['select'] == 'allitems') {
                                $_SESSION['s'] = "allitems";
                            }
                            if ($_POST['select'] == 'available') {
                                $_SESSION['s'] = "available";
                            }
                        }
                        //order to show it in
                        if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
                            if ($_POST['order'] == 'id_asc') {
                                $_SESSION['o'] = "id_asc";
                            }
                            if ($_POST['order'] == 'id_desc') {
                                $_SESSION['o'] = "id_desc";
                            }
                            if ($_POST['order'] == 'name_asc') {
                                $_SESSION['o'] = "name_asc";
                            }
                            if ($_POST['order'] == 'name_desc') {
                                $_SESSION['o'] = "name_desc";
                            }
                        }
                        //layout
                        if (isset($_POST['layout'])) {
                            if ($_POST['layout'] == 'row') {
                                $_SESSION['l'] = "row";
                            }
                            if ($_POST['layout'] == 'grid') {
                                $_SESSION['l'] = "grid";
                            }
                        }
                        //have query update take place
                        if (isset($_SESSION['s']) || isset($_SESSION['o']) || isset($_SESSION['l'])) {
                            $_SESSION['dbstore'] = ['select' => $_SESSION['s'], 'order' => $_SESSION['o'], 'layout' => $_SESSION['l']];
                            $query_string = http_build_query($_SESSION['dbstore']);
                            header('Location: store' . (FALSE === empty($query_string) ? '?'.$query_string:''));
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
```

Now there are also some other changes but that's because all this code was meant for a dashboard that I'm building in an admin area, Now there were also other forms on the page wich I later found out were broken by `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`

So that's not really a relevant change to my question, the solution was to my question was to change `$s` to `$SESSION['s']` when a new layout change got applied so *not* when they were received by `$_GET`. At first I was convinced the problem was with setting the default states of the layout. And even though that might still be the case it got fixed by changing something else.

I hope this was somehow still a bit clear and that it helped someone maybe even if it was just an other idea of doing things since it is a weird way of doing things.

Thanks for the answers everyone they helped me a bit with php in general.